# Modify Chrome extension using source code

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, synchronization, edit, web-sql

I have added an extension from the webstore that I want to modify to my own needs. The information from the extension I want is in the WebSQL which only stores locally. I want to modify the extension so the WebSQL syncs so I can access it on my other devices or to get the information stored elsewhere (besides the websql) but still have it accessible on my other devices. I have unzipped the files and have found an app online to edit the manifest, but I cannot open any .js files on my computer to edit. I can view all the content in the chrome extension source viewer from the webstore. However, I can not pin point where I change the sync settings

Comment: The only thing I could find online was this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxS3ds8FETY    -I don't know if this is accurate or what software I need to edit the manifest

Comment: Dear user (evading a question ban from your other account, but that's beside the point), this is not as simple as "sync setting". WebSQL data has no sync mechanism, and to add one would require significant and extension/use-specific rewrite to the code which is in no way simple. This is outside your current scope of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the full source code of the extension by using [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin?hl=en).

Using this extension you can view or download the zip file. Unzip to a particular folder and edit from there. I think the verified_contents.json is not required.